# Is there a way in which i can give the following matrix as an input to a kmeans clustering program?

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, k-means

imagine I have the following "Pageview matrix"
COLUMN HEADINGS:  books placement resources br aca

Each row represents a session

so this is my matrix,sample:

4 5 0 2 2
1 2 1 7 3
1 3 6 1 6

saved in a .txt file

Can i give this as an input to a k-means program and obtain clusters based on the highest frequency of occurrence??
 How do i use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i give this as an input to a k-means program and obtain clusters based on the highest frequency of occurrence?

This is not what k-means does.

You can feed it to a k-means algorithm though. Each row is just a point in a 5d space - what part are you having trouble with?